# the merge sorting part doesn't work

Tags: java

```
//this package is for the compare to and other methods
```

package teststudent;

```
public class Student {
private String name;
private String status;
private int grade1;
private int grade2;
private int grade3;
private double average;
public Student(String name, int grade1, int grade2, int grade3)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.grade1 = grade1;
    this.grade2 = grade2;
    this.grade3 = grade3;
    computeAverage();
    computeStatus();

}

public double compareTo( Student s){

        return average - s.average;


        }

public void computeAverage(){
                  average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
}


public void computeStatus(){
       if ( average < 70) {
            status = "Failing";
        }
        else {
            status = "Passing";
        }

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public int getGrade1() {
    return grade1;
}

public int getGrade2() {
    return grade2;
}

public int getGrade3() {
    return grade3;
}

public double getAverage() {
    return average;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public void setGrade1(int grade1) {
    this.grade1 = grade1;
}

public void setGrade2(int grade2) {
    this.grade2 = grade2;
}

public void setGrade3(int grade3) {
    this.grade3 = grade3;
}

public void setAverage(double average) {
    this.average = average;
}



   }
```

in this package is where i have the problem
       package teststudent;

```
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;

  import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
 import javax.xml.crypto.Data;
  class StudentList {





ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
private Scanner input; 
private PrintWriter output;

public StudentList(){

}

public void readStudents(){
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser ();
    if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        java.io.File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        try {
            input = new Scanner(file);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

this is for reading files
            while(input.hasNextLine()){
                    String dataLine = input.nextLine();
                    String[] data = dataLine.split("[|]");
                    Student student = new Student(data[0],          Integer.parseInt(data[1]), Integer.parseInt(data[2]),           Integer.parseInt(data[3]));
                    students.add(student);
                    }

```
        input.close();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No file selected.");
    }
}

public  void sortStudents(){
```

here is where i have the problem when it gets to the merge sorting it  gimme an error and i don't know way
    students.get(1).getAverage();

```
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfList.length; i++)
       if (sizeOfList.length>1){ 
           double[] firstHalf = new double [sizeOfList.length/2];
           System.arraycopy(sizeOfList, 0, firstHalf, 0sizeOfList.length/2);
           mergeSort(firstHalf);

           int secondHalfLenght = sizeOfList.length - sizeOfList.length/2;
           double[] secondHalf = new double[secondHalfLenght];
           System.arraycopy(sizeOfList, sizeOfList.length/2, secondHalf, 0,secondHalfLenght);
           merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, sizeOfList);

       }   
}

    public  void merge(double[] list1, double[] list2, double[] average){
        int current1 = 0;
        int current2 = 0;
        int current3 = 0;
        while( current1 < list1.length &&  current2 < list2.length){
        if (list1[current1] <list2[current2])
            average[current3++] = list1[current1++];
        else
            average[current3++] = list2[current2++];
    }
        while (current1 < list1.length) 
            average[current3++] = list1[current2++];
        while (current2 < list2.length)
            average[current3++] = list2[current2++];

    }
    private void mergeSort( ){
        int [] sizeOfList;
        sizeOfList = students.size();
    mergeSort(sizeOfList);


                  // System.out.println(sizeOfList[i] + "");
 //the error ends here everything else is ok with the program
    }
 //this it to print to a file
  public void writeStudents(){
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        java.io.File  file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        try {
            output = new PrintWriter(file);
            String name = "Name";
            String grade1 = "Grade 1";
            String grade2 = "Grade 2";
            String grade3 = "Grade 3";
            String avg = "Average";
            String status = "Status";
                  output.printf("%15s %15s %15s %15s %15s %14s %n", name,    grade1,grade2, grade3, avg, status);
            for(int i = 0; i <= students.size() - 1; i++){
                output.printf("%15s %15.2f %15.2f %15.2f %15.2f %15s %n", 
                                    students.get(i).getName(),
                                    (double)students.get(i).getGrade1(),
                                    (double)students.get(i).getGrade2(),
                                    (double)students.get(i).getGrade3(),
                                    students.get(i).getAverage(),
                                    students.get(i).getStatus());
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
        output.close();             
        }
    }        



    private void mergeSort(int sizeOfList) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
}


}
  //this  is the main package and cannot be modify 
     package teststudent;

       public class TestStudent {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   StudentList studentList = new StudentList();

   studentList.readStudents(); 

       studentList.writeStudents();    

         studentList.sortStudents(); 

       studentList.writeStudents();
}

  }
```

Comment: JavaScript has NOTHING to do with Java. I removed the tag

Comment: Please read about how to post an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This code is most definitely not "M".

Comment: Small issue, but in reality not so small: better do `average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3.0;` as now you are doing integer division, rounding down ;)

Comment: yeah  but my problem is in the sorting part that i need to get the  average from the arraylist so that it can be sorter